# image uploaded cant be shown

Tags: images

im using wordpress 3.2.1
i kinda forgot how this things happen..but i remember updating some plugins/wp
and its happen.

i can upload an image, but once its finished it show broken link. 
something like this 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/688/screenshot20110721at639.png/

anyone can help? already try deactivate all plugins but nothing happen.
already empty the "Store uploads in this folder" but nothing happen too

anyone can help?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think, the problem is file permission. by default wordpress 3.2.1 come  with folder permission 751, and file permission 640. so, will not visible to see in internet browser.

do this: change uploads folder permission to 755, so every time you uploads image will have 644 permission.

check other file in upload/year/month folder: change all file with permission 640 to 644.